# What character is this:?

Tags: unicode, character, special-characters

**EDIT**
While posting the question, character I ask for was shown well to me, but after postig it does not show up anymore. As it does not appear, please look up in original [site](https://www.raamatukoi.ee/cgi-bin/sari?244)

**EDIT2**
I looked for Unicode chars associated with "alien", and found no matching ones. Here is how they are compared side by side:

[image: two aliens side by side]

I found, that some texts inside my database contain character like . I am not sure, how it would rendered with different fonts and environments, so here is the image, how I see it:
[image: some weird alien-like character]

I tried to identify it with different ways. For example, when I paste it into Sublime Text, it automatically shows as control character `<0x85>`. When I tried to identify it in different unicode-detectors (http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html, https://unicode-table.com/en/, https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl), their conclusion is pretty match the same:

```
Uni­code code point char­acter             U+0085
UTF-8 en­co­ding                           c2 85 hexa­decimal
                                         194 133 deci­mal
                                         0302 0205 octal
Uni­co­de char­ac­ter name                   <control>
Uni­co­de 1.0 char­act­er name (de­pre­ca­ted)  NEXT LINE (NEL)
```

https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl
also included this information

```
HTML en­co­ding                            … &#x85;  hexa­decimal
                                         … &#133;  deci­mal
```

which gave me some vague hint, how it was possible, that `…` become ``. But this is not main problem here.

My question is: how is possible, that control character is shown up like this and what is the actual glyph used to represent it?

I tried to sketch into http://shapecatcher.com/ to  identify it but without success. I did not find such a glyph in any Unicode table.

Comment: Paste the text into your question. It doesn't matter how it's rendered.

Comment: @JGNI, thank you for notification, I did not notice the disappearance after posting ;)

Comment: I do not find on original site. And are you sure it is a character and not an image? Or just a special font (with special images), like the glyphicon fonts? Check source code of the page.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi May I ask, what is the character you see before ' ja muinasjutt avaneb'? Unfortunately I am sure, it is character. If it would be image, you could see it too. But as character it may not show up as it in every env.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I looked the original site on Windows machine (I use Linux), and there was square instead this character, as shown on missing characters,

Comment: @w.k. Ah, ok now I understand. I see just a white space (so the "ja" is misaligned).  But so, I see also it as U-0085, so it depends on fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alien symbol is not a Unicode character; but is in Microsoft's **Webdings** font, with character code **0x85**. Running **Start > Run > charmap**, then selecting **Webdings** from the **Font** drop list, opens this window:

[image: webdings1]

If I click that alien character in the leftmost column, the message **Character Code : 0x85** is shown at the bottom of the window.

[image: webdings2]

I can even copy that character from the **Character Map** and paste it into Microsoft Wordpad:

[image: webdings3]

[The WebDings symbols were included in Unicode Release 7](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/): *Pictographic symbols (including many emoji), geometric symbols, arrows, and ornaments originating from the Wingdings and **Webdings** sets*. Therefore you would expect the alien symbol to also be in Unicode. However, I don't think the version of **Webdings** that was used included that alien symbol, since Windows 10 also has a *ttf* file for **Webdings** (version 5.01), and it also does not include the alien symbol:

[image: webdings4]

So presumably what originally caught your attention was some text being rendered with an older version of the **Webdings** font which included that alien symbol.

Comment: It seems certainly the right character. At first I was in doubt, because it appears on Ubuntu Linux, but then I recalled I have installed MS Core Fonts. It is still surprising it is rendered in context, where should used Verdana. Thank you for clearing the topic!

Answer (score 0):

The glyph is  [U+1F47D EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN](https://codepoints.net/U+1F47D). I don't know why your system misrenders a control character.

Comment: no, they are completely different glyphs, as you may see from my second edit now.